# Multiple Square objects gets selected when clicking into them

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've created a function that recognise the Square objects and when clicking in one of them they are suppose to change color but when I click any of them more than one gets selected even if they are not in the same position. When I click again all of them gets selected and change color.

What am I doing wrong?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Launchpad</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="appArea"></canvas>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css/style.css

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

canvas {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

js/app.js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('appArea');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var shapelist = [];


var Square = function (x, y, size, ctx) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.selected = false;
}

Square.prototype.render = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    if (this.selected) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "gold";
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();

};


var generateSquares = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        var theX = i * 40;
        var theY = i * 3;
        var theSize = 30;
        var square = new Square(theX, theY, theSize, ctx);
        square.render();
        shapelist.push(square);
    };
}

var getCoords = function (x, y) {
    var validCoords = [];

    for(index in this.shapelist){
        var shape = this.shapelist[index];
        var startX = shape.x;
        var endX = shape.x + shape.size;
        var startY = shape.y;
        var endY = shape.y + shape.size;

        if (x >= startX && x <= endX && y >= startY && y <= endY) {
            validCoords.push(shape);
        }
    }
    return validCoords;
} 


var startEvent = function(e) {
    var self = this;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        var shapes = getCoords(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        if (shapes.length) {
            var selectedShape = shapes[shapes.length-1];
            selectedShape.selected = true;
        }
        render();
    }, false);
}



var render = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    for(index in shapelist){
        shapelist[index].render();
    }
}

generateSquares();
startEvent();
render();
```

Comment: set up a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ to increase your chances to get an anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are only settings selected to false in the constructor, nowhere else.

So the count of selected squares will only keep growing.

So if you want one single selected square, reset all square's 'selected' property prior to setting one to true.

2) re-read your render function : the color will always be this.color, which happens to be undefined with the code provided.

3) Other thing is you refer to this.shapelist into a globally defined function, getCoords : you'll just get a reference error, which won't get notified since it's called inside an event handler.

everything is fixed in this fiddle here :

http://jsfiddle.net/4bqtU/

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    var shapes = getCoords(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    if (shapes.length) {
        resetShapeSelection();
        var selectedShape = shapes[shapes.length-1];
        selectedShape.selected = true;
    }
    render();
}, false);

function resetShapeSelection() {
    for(index in shapelist){
       var shape = shapelist[index];
       shape.selected=false;
    }
 }
```